# New Python 3.8 install - getting error trying to run a py in IDLE - AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'popen4'

Tags: import, attributes, subprocess, popen

I just did a clean install of windows 10 pro and also updated to Python 3.8.  Now I am getting an error when I try to run from the IDLE shell.  This script previously ran fine on Python 2.7 before I rebuilt my machine and reinstalled windows and upgraded Python.  How can I sort out the error?

The line of code that dies is line 2 below:

```
    import os
    p = os.popen4(r'cmd /k')
```

Any suggestions on how to fix the error?

Thanks,
LarmanW